# How do we write Unit test cases (Jasmine) for nested functions?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

am writing a test case for the following scenario.The code coverage is not fully covered. I don't know whether it's possible to write or not. if I ask anything wrong means kindly guide me to write a test case for this scenario and  avoid this problem in future.At-least tell its possible or not

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .component("testLockCtrl", {
            templateUrl: 'wwwroot/html/myLocation/testLock.html',
            controller: 'testLockCtrl as vm'
        })
        .controller("testLockCtrl", testLockCtrl);

    testLockCtrl.$inject = ['SessionService', 'HttpRequestSoapAPI'];
    /*Parent Controller*/
    function testLockCtrl($rootScope, $mdDialog) {

         vm.ChangeDataController=ChangeDataController;
        /*childer controller*/
        function ChangeDataController($scope) {
            $scope.tempData = true;
           /*following functions (child of change data controller) can  called in click*/
            $scope.editData = function() {

                $scope.tempData = false;
            }


            $scope.editDatas = function() {

                /*some code*/
            }

        }

        function addData() {
            TC$DialogMgr.tag(function(tagID) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    locals: { testCase: vm },
                    controller: ChangeDataController,
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    templateUrl: "wwwroot/html/myLocation/addData.html",
                    clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    preserveScope: true,
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }).then(function() {

                }, function() {

                }).finally(function() {
                    TC$DialogMgr.unTag(tagID);
                });
            }, TC$DialogMgr.type.Input);
        }
    }

})();

it("Should check if Module Flag status is received", function () {
        var data = [{ loc: 'mde', Status: -1 }];
        testLockCtrl.ChangeDataController(data);
        var testData=testLockCtrl.editDatas ()
        expect(testData).toBeDefined();

    })
```

Above is my test case it can cover up to child controller and not its nested functions.Do we can access the scope variable in test Case from controller.js file. And also code coverage only covers ChangeDataController function alone, not its inner side functions. Kindly help me to write a test case and clear my doubt.

Comment: As the answer suggests, every function that should be spied or mocked should be exposed as scope (or controller) method.

Comment: hi estus i  have updated my code.And can you give a try to  find what i did as wrong?

Comment: You did not exposed addData as a method, and editDatas is for some reason is set within ChangeDataController. There's no reason at all to use $scope like that in component, this is antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should expose those inner functions or test them indirectly. Wherever the `addData` method is being called, you can just make sure you have tested that function and pass in different parameters to the calling function.

Or if you add `addData` to the `$scope` you can test more easily:

```
$scope.addData = function() { /* ... */ };
```

In your test:

```
var result = controller.addData(...);
expect(result).toBe(expected);
```

Comment: i have tried it same way but i cant.i have update my code can you please see it?